# Is an Apple Push Notification service SSL Certificate necessary when using an APNs key for sending notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I have been tasked with maintaining an iOS app with push notifications enabled. There is a production "Apple Push Notification service SSL Certificate" associated with the app's `Identifier` on `developer.apple.com` that expires soon. Also, under `Keys` there is a key with the `Apple Push Notifications service (APNs)` enabled. It *appears* that the backend server sending out the push notifications is only using this key and not the certificate.

Is it safe to let the `Apple Push Notification service SSL Certificate` expire? And what problems might occur if the certificate turns out to be in use somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

in my experience, you app stop receive push notification.
And wait you client to complaint about this. You must renew APns Certificate and voip certificate every year.